# How to append date to batch file on Windows XP

Tags: windows, rename

Suppose I have the files as below

```
C
|_tmp
    |_a.txt
    |_b.txt
    |_c.txt
```

I use `rename *.txt 20110822*.txt`, but not works.
Could anyone please suggest a method to append date in front of the files, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do rename %%i 20110822%%i
```

Note that the double-percent-signs are only needed in a batch file.  From an interactive command line, use only one percent-sign.